# Performing Custom validation on a attribute based datatype set

Tags: c#, class, validation, abstraction

I am currently in a situation where I need to design a scheme for how I would validate a class based on the value of one of its member variables - in this case the value of an enum.

The custom validation could consist of getting the min or max length for a certain enum and something different for a different enum?

Simple example

```
public class preferredFuelType {
    ValidationRule validation
    Cartype Car
}

public Cartype {
    Hybrid, 
    Electric,
    Gas,
    Bio
}
```

The Cartype instance will have a specific enum, I need to make sure that value Inserted into that Table fit the custom validation I have set, for which the criteria (an upper or lower value) is set by the user.

But how do I abstract the validation the class outside the class?

My initial solution would be to list all criteria in the same class, and make setter function for the enum which also sets the appropriate variables, but this also leaves rest null, or created unnecessarily..

Comment: Can you give us some more concrete examples of inputs/outputs, use cases?

Comment: So in essence, I just want allow the user to define the type of column he wants use for a table, via the enum, once enum has been decided, one will have to fill out a specific set of validation variables which is tied to this type, it could the max range each entry can be within this column. Problem here is due to the enum..